# kotlin, firebase recycleview load only last element

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

The app must show all product but show only last (number 6). when i launch app, work, but return this error : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. I'm beginner in android language and searching online i didn't find nothing.
the app was composed from mainActivity and CartActivity
output
[image]

this is realtime DB

[image]
this is main code

```
    package com.example.tpsi_maccagnola


import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.events.UpdateCarrello
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.listener.cartlistener
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.listener.foodListener
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.modelli.Carrello
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.modelli.Food
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), foodListener, cartlistener {
    lateinit var foodListener: foodListener
    lateinit var cartlistener1: cartlistener

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
    }


    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(UpdateCarrello::class.java))
            EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(UpdateCarrello::class.java)
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN, sticky = true)
     fun onUpdateCart(event: UpdateCarrello) {
        counCartDB()
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        init()

        caricaDB()

        counCartDB()


    }

    private fun counCartDB() {
        val cartmodels: MutableList<Carrello> = ArrayList()
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("carrello")
            .child("UNIQUE_USER_ID")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (cartsnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val cartmodel = cartsnapshot.getValue(Carrello::class.java)
                        cartmodel!!.key = cartsnapshot.key
                        cartmodels.add(cartmodel)

                    }
                    cartlistener1.onCartSuccess(cartmodels)
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    cartlistener1.onCartFailed(error.message)
                }

            })
    }

    private fun caricaDB() {
        val foods: MutableList<Food> = ArrayList()
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Food").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {

                        for (FoodSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                            val foodModel = FoodSnapshot.getValue(Food::class.java)
                            foodModel!!.key = FoodSnapshot.key
                            foods.add(foodModel)
                        }
                        foodListener.onloadsuccess(foods)


                    } else {
                        foodListener.onloadfailed("non esiste")


                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    foodListener.onloadfailed(error.message)
                }

            })
    }

    private fun init() {
        foodListener = this
        cartlistener1 = this
        val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
        food_recycler.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        food_recycler.addItemDecoration(decoration())

        btnCart.setOnClickListener{ startActivity(Intent(this,CartActivity::class.java))}
    }

    override fun onloadsuccess(foodModelList: List<Food>?) {
        val adapter = FoodAdapter(this, foodModelList!!, cartlistener1)
        food_recycler.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onloadfailed(message: String?) {
        Snackbar.make(layoutprincipale, message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onCartSuccess(carrelloList: List<Carrello>) {
        var cartTot = 0
        for (cartlist in carrelloList!!) {
            cartTot += cartlist!!.quantita

/*badge!!.setNumber(cartTot)*/


        }


    }

    override fun onCartFailed(message: String?) {
        Snackbar.make(layoutprincipale, message!!, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

this is adapter

```
    package com.example.tpsi_maccagnola

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.events.UpdateCarrello
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.listener.RecyclerListener
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.listener.cartlistener
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.modelli.Carrello
import com.example.tpsi_maccagnola.modelli.Food
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus

class FoodAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val list: List<Food>,
    private val cartlistener1: cartlistener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.FoodHolder>() {

    class FoodHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
         var imageView: ImageView?= null
         var txtName: TextView?= null
         var txtprice: TextView?= null

        private var clickListener: RecyclerListener? = null

        fun setClickListener (clickListener: RecyclerListener){
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        init {
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView;
            txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName) as TextView;
            txtprice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtprice) as TextView;


            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            clickListener!!.onclcickProdotto(p0,adapterPosition )
        }

    }





    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FoodHolder {
        return FoodHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_food,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FoodHolder, position: Int) {
        Glide.with(context).load(list[position].image).into(holder.imageView!!)
        holder.txtName!!.text =StringBuilder().append(list[position].name)
        holder.txtprice!!.text =StringBuilder("€").append(list[position].price)


        holder.setClickListener(object: RecyclerListener{
            override fun onclcickProdotto(view: View?, position: Int) {
                aggiungiCarrello(list[position])
            }

        } )
    }

    private fun aggiungiCarrello(food: Food) {

val utenteCart = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child("UNIQUE_USER_ID")

        utenteCart.child(Food.key!!).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
if(snapshot.exists()){ //se è gia presente aggiorno

    val cartmodel = snapshot.getValue(Carrello::class.java)
    val updatecart: MutableMap<String,Any> = HashMap()

    cartmodel!!.quantita = cartmodel!!.quantita+1
    updatecart["quantita"] = cartmodel!!.quantita
    updatecart["totale"] =cartmodel!!.quantita * cartmodel.price!!.toFloat()

    utenteCart.child(food.key!!)
        .updateChildren(updatecart)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(UpdateCarrello())

            cartlistener1.onCartFailed("aggiunto correttamente")

        }.addOnFailureListener{e -> cartlistener1.onCartFailed(e.message)
        }

}else{
    val carrello1 = Carrello
    carrello1.key = food.key
    carrello1.name = food.name
    carrello1.image = food.image
    carrello1.price = food.price
    carrello1.quantita = 1
    carrello1.totale = food.price!!.toFloat()

    utenteCart.child(food.key!!)
        .setValue(carrello1)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(UpdateCarrello())
            cartlistener1.onCartFailed("aggiunto correttamente")

        }.addOnFailureListener{e -> cartlistener1.onCartFailed(e.message)
        }



}
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
cartlistener1.onCartFailed(error.message)
            }


        })
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      return list.size
    }

}
```

Comment: use `log.d` on the adapter list and see if it portrays the data correctly.

Comment: @UndefinedBug1.0  I do not know how to use it

Comment: 01, 02, and so on, are direct children of your root reference? So you want only to get the last 6?